# How do I turn with the keyboard while taxiing in a DC3?

Tags: ms-flight-simulator-2004

I'm trying to find the key to turn left and right while taxiing in a DC3. (I don't have a joystick.)

On planes like the Cessna I can just use the the left and right arrows on my laptop keyboard, but for the DC3 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keys for rudder control.  By default they are Num Pad 0 and Numpad Enter.  Use Num Pad 5 to quickly center the rudder while taxiing.

Here is a good keyboard reference for FS2004.  http://www.nrick.net/html/fs2004_keyboard_.html